# How can I use hardware-specific software on Linux?

Tags: software-recommendation

I've recently switched to Linux and it feels really good! But, the only problem I'm encountering is, that I can't use the software which I used to use for configuring my hardware. For example, there was an app from MSI to customize the settings of my motherboard. There was also an app to configure the macro keys of my mouse.

But, after switching to Linux, I can not configure my hardware because of the lack of apps for Linux. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Inquire of your motherboard manufacturer for Linux support.